# Can't find context menu in ContextMenuOpening

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I am trying to replace a header in the context menu based on the data context of the selected row.

ContextMenuOpening fires, but then I am unable to find the context menu from there.

```
<UserControl ContextMenuOpening="AddItemHeader">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="RowMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="&lt;to be set>"
                  Tag="delete menu item"
                  Click="MarkForDeletion">
        </MenuItem>
        [...]
    </ContextMenu>
    <Style x:Key="DefaultRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>
```

.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
    [...]
```

.

```
private void AddItemHeader(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ContextMenuOpening fired.");

        FrameworkElement fe = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
        ContextMenu menu = fe.ContextMenu;

        if (menu == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu not found!");
            return;
        }

        MenuItem menuItem = null;

        foreach (MenuItem mi in menu.Items) {
            if ((string)mi.Tag == "to be set") {
                menuItem = mi;
            }
        }

        if (menuItem == null) {
            return;
            Console.WriteLine("Item not found!");
        }
}
```

Which just outputs "Menu not found!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the context menu to every row.
You can't find the context menu because the sender of the ContextMenuOpening is probably the grid and not the row.

I would assign the context menu to the datagrid and in the event handler of every menu item use the selecteditem of datagrid.

Comment: Thank you, this lets me find the menu. But now I can't seem to get the Data Context to read the selected row. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764013/cant-find-datacontext-in-contextmenuopening

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rowIndex = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
var row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedIndex);
ContextMenu cm = row.ContextMenu;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.