# Can't find DataContext in ContextMenuOpening

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I am trying to add a context menu for my data grid that will display a certain menu item header depending on the selected row. For example if the row is not marked for deletion there will be a menu item "Mark for deletion". Otherwise it will say "Unmark for deletion".

I don't think I am setting the DataContext for the ContextMenu correctly, so I am unable to get information from the selected row.

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="OrdersGrid"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentlySelected,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                ContextMenuOpening="AddItemHeader">
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="dummy"
                                  Click="MarkForDeletion">                                
                        </MenuItem>
```

.

```
private void AddItemHeader(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ContextMenuOpening fired.");

        FrameworkElement fe = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
        ContextMenu menu = fe.ContextMenu;


        if (menu == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu not found!");
            return;
        }

        MenuItem menuItem = null;

        foreach (Object o in menu.Items) {
            if (o is MenuItem)
            {
                if ((string)(o as MenuItem).Header == "dummy")
                {
                    menuItem = o as MenuItem;
                }
            }         
        }

        if (menuItem == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Item not found!");
            return;                
        }

        if (menu.DataContext == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data Context not found!");
            return; 
        }

        OrderModel selectedItem = menu.DataContext as OrderModel;

        if (selectedItem == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can't get order from row!");
            return;
        }

        if (selectedItem.MarkedForDeletion)
        {
            menuItem.Header = "Unmark for deletion";
        }
        else
        {
            menuItem.Header = "Mark for deletion";
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
ContextMenuOpening fired.
Data Context not found!
```

Comment: ContextMenus are part of the `AdornerLayer`, which is different from the main `VisualTree` used by most of WPF's UI objects, so the `DataContext` isn't inherited in the same way. You can find the UI object the Menu is on by using the `PlacementTarget` property, and can find your `SelectedItem` from there. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11211901/302677) for an example

Comment: Thanks Rachel. I have made various attempts using PlacementTarget but I am very unfamiliar with XAML syntax and everything I tried has failed.

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit] your post with your updated code? I think what you'll be looking for would be something like `menu.PlacementTarget.DataContext`

Comment: No changes as nothing I tried worked. I'm giving up on this approach for now. Thank you for your help!